# C++: Weird pointer corruption error

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, mpi

I have the following situation: I have written some short MPI testcodes in order to find out which combination of send and receive operations works best in my code.

The code works perfectly fine on my own computer (tested with 8 processes), but as soon as I run it one the cluster I'm working on, I get a huge error output of a corrupted or doubly freed pointer, this is the output: http://pastebin.com/pXTRSf89

What I am doing in my code is the following: I call my communication function 100K times and measure the time. This function is shown below. What I found out, is that the error always happens in the same iteration (somewhere around 6K). The reported processorID does change however. The iteration is the same even if I use 64 procs instead of 8. The problem is: I have absolutely no idea, what could be wrong, especilly since there are no pointer freed or assigned.

```
void communicateGrid(int level, real* grid, const Subdomain& subdomain, std::vector<TimeMap>& tm_) {
    tm_[level]["CommGrid"].start();

    MPI_Status status[2];
    MPI_Request request[2];

    // x 
    MPI_Isend(&grid[getIndexInner(level, 1, 1, 1) + innerGridpoints_[level][0] - numOuterGridpoints_[level]], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 1], subdomain.upperNeighbors[0], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    MPI_Isend(&grid[getIndexInner(level, 1, 1, 1)], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 1], subdomain.lowerNeighbors[0], 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);

    MPI_Recv(&grid[getIndexInner(level, 1,1,1) + innerGridpoints_[level][0]], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 1], subdomain.upperNeighbors[0], 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[0]);
    MPI_Recv(&grid[getIndexInner(level, 1,1,1) - numOuterGridpoints_[level]], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 1], subdomain.lowerNeighbors[0], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[1]);

    //y 
    MPI_Isend(&grid[getIndex(level, 0, innerGridpoints_[level][1], 0)], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 2], subdomain.upperNeighbors[1], 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    MPI_Isend(&grid[getIndex(level, 0, numOuterGridpoints_[level], 0)], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 2], subdomain.lowerNeighbors[1], 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);

    MPI_Recv(&grid[getIndex(level, 0, innerGridpoints_[level][1] + numOuterGridpoints_[level], 0)], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 2], subdomain.upperNeighbors[1], 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[0]);
    MPI_Recv(grid, 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 2], subdomain.lowerNeighbors[1], 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[1]);

    // z
    MPI_Isend(&grid[getIndex(level, 0, 0, innerGridpoints_[level][2])], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 3], subdomain.upperNeighbors[2], 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[0]);
    MPI_Isend(&grid[getIndex(level, 0, 0, numOuterGridpoints_[level])], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 3], subdomain.lowerNeighbors[2], 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request[1]);

    MPI_Recv(&grid[getIndex(level, 0, 0, numOuterGridpoints_[level] + innerGridpoints_[level][2])], 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 3], subdomain.upperNeighbors[2], 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[0]);
    MPI_Recv(grid, 1, mpiTypes_[level * 4 + 3], subdomain.lowerNeighbors[2], 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status[1]);

    tm_[level]["CommGrid"].stop();
}
```

mpiTypes_ is a global variable of type MPI_Datatype*, innerGridpoints_ and numOuterGridpoints_ are global as well (I know that this is not a good coding style, but I took it only for timing). 
I'm pretty sure that my Datatypes are correct, as they work in another setup of communicaton functions (e.g. Irecv followed by Send).

Final Note: I just tried to run this with just one processes. Then the following error occured:

> Rank 0 [Mon Apr 22 02:11:23 2013] [c0-0c1s3n0] Fatal error in
>   PMPI_Isend: Internal MPI error!, error stack: PMPI_Isend(148):
>   MPI_Isend(buf=0x2aaaab7b531c, count=1, dtype=USER, dest=0,
>   tag=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, request=0x7fffffffb4d4) failed (unknown)():
>   Internal MPI error!
>   _pmiu_daemon(SIGCHLD): [NID 00070] [c0-0c1s3n0] [Mon Apr 22 02:11:23 2013] PE RANK 0 exit signal Aborted

Again, this happened only on the cluster, but worked on my machine.

I am happy for anything would I could check or where the error might be!
Thanks

Comment: What brand of CPU does it work on and what brand of CPU does it fail on?

Comment: I wonder whether your pointers ever end up pointing to blocks of data that they shouldn't. When you do things like `&grid[getIndex(level, 0, 0, numOuterGridpoints_[level] + innerGridpoints_[level][2])]`, is there any chance that that points to a block that isn't yours? Or could there be a memory leak in the function you are calling... is it the exact same version of compiler / libraries on both machines?

Comment: getIndex and getInnerIndex are just inlined index functions, as grid is a 3d-array, they should be fine. My PC is a Intel i5, compiled with gcc 4.6.0 (Mac system) - the cluster is a Cray machine with Opteron CPUs. I tried but the standard PGI compiler as well as the gcc (version 4.6.3)

Comment: What happens if you run this inside gdb - maybe you will get more helpful information about the state of things than with the stack trace? As a desperate debug trick, I would explicitly compute the value of all the parameters (pointers etc) that you pass to the functions, assign them to a separate set of variables, and print them out for each iteration (to file). Then call the function with the "short" expressions. Inspecting these values may give you a clue.  Could threads somehow be clashing? At what level is the multi-threading happening? Any shared resources not getting protected?

Comment: Well that is the big problem: I don't know how to run this in gdb on the cluster. The Cray doc does have some information about it, but that doesn't seem to work on the machine I'm working on and the people I could ask are gone til Wednesday. The weird thing is: If there was an error with the indexes, it should crash right in the first iteration, shouldn't it? As they do not change over time. However, it only crashes in the 6000th or so iteration. Anyway, thanks for your ideas so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Wait or Test or something on those MPI Requests created by the `MPI_Isend()`, or you will leak internal resources, and eventually crash, which is what's happening.

Jeff Squyres puts it very well in his [blog post at Cisco](http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/dont-leak-mpi_requests/).

*You* know that those Isends are completing, but the MPI library has no way of knowing this and cleaning up the resources allocated and pointed to by those `MPI_Request`s.  How much and what kind of resources are required depends on a lot of things, including the underlying network connection (can take up scarce infiniband resources, for instance), so it's not necessarily surprising that it worked on your own machine but not on the cluster.

You can fix this by adding

```
MPI_Waitall(2, request,  status);
```

after each stage of `MPI_Isend`/`MPI_Recv()`s.

This is not just necessary for cleaning up resources, it's actually required for correctness of a program with nonblocking requests.

Comment: Indeed, now it works, thanks. Never knew that this was necessary, I always thought you could avoid the Waits if you knew that all gets received correctly